# Meaning of "I thought I broke the last of that breakdown"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this lyric from Wrabel's 11 blocks?

> *I thought I broke the last of that breakdown, when I sold your winter coat*

I understand how you break something but how do you break the "last of that breakdown?"

Comment: In idiomatic expression, this seems to mean something like "the last straw on the camel's back". As per wikipedia, this idiomatic expression "describes the seemingly minor or routine action which causes an unpredictably large and sudden reaction, because of the cumulative effect of small actions". Hope this clarifies the meaning of the expression you are looking for.

Comment: By the way, it really helped that you had named the song and artist from which this lyric came, but it would have really helped if you had included the lyrics themselves (especially the lyric preceding this one) or had included a link. The lyric preceding this one is what had helped me figure out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The singer is still in love with the person who had owned the winter coat.

The singer had thought he had been over the other person, but he had been wrong.

In other words,

> **I thought I** had already gotten over (**broke**) the last remnants of my depression over losing you (**the last of that breakdown**), when I sold your winter coat.

Does this help?